# Reading reloadable xml file from external Tomcat directory

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, apache-camel

**Prerequisites**

- Apache Tomcat 7
- Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE
- Apache Camel 2.14.1
- My Webapplication is deployed in ${catalina.home}/webapps/ as usual

**Requirements**

- Reading xml file placed **outside of war-Archive** (for example from ${catalina.home}/myfolder/)
- The xml file should be **reloadable**. So if the xml changes the new xml file should be available in my Webapplication
- The xml file should be **mapped to Java-Objects**

**First try**

I have added the file to classpath via tomcat in `catalina.home`/conf/catalina.properties:

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/myfolder/
```

The file is placed here: 
${catalina.home}/myfolder/myFile.xml

Reading and mapping the file to Java-Objects works via a timer in apache camel.

```
from("timer://myTimer?fixedRate=true&period=20000")
.setBody(simple("resource:classpath:myFile.xml"))
.unmarshal(myFileJaxbDataFormat)
.process(myFileTimerProcessor);
```

myFileTimerProcessor takes the mapped Objects and stores it to a Spring-Bean.
This Bean is used by other Camel-Routes to access the Data contained in the xml file.

**Problem**

As Claus Ibsen mentioned below the problem is that the ClassLoader caches the file. So the file is not read again if data in it has changed.
If the file ${catalina.home}/myfolder/myFile.xml changes it should be read again and the new values should be available to the timer so it can read the new values for the application.

Is there a possibility to read a xml file outside of war-Archive and reload it if it's content changes?

Is there a more common wary to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Max

**EDIT 1:**
I have restructured the question to ask not only specific details.

Comment: Is it maybe you have somewhere set `contentCache=true`? (http://camel.apache.org/stringtemplate.html)

Answer (score 1):

The file is cached by the Java classloader, not something Camel can do anything about. You likely need to load the file using file resources instead of classpath.