# Reading reloadable xml file from external directory in Tomcat

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, tomcat

My requirement is similar to that of [Reading reloadable xml file from external Tomcat directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829601/reading-reloadable-xml-file-from-external-tomcat-directory)

I need to place my hibernate xml and property file outside of the exploded war file ie, inside tomcat/my_folder

I am importing this xml and the property file through **applicationcontext.xml** using the below code.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:D:/my_folder/jdbc.properties" />  
</bean>

<!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
<import resource="file:D:/my_folder/hibernate-context.xml" />
```

The import of these files works fine but i when i update these files, the changes are not reflecting unless i restart Tomcat.

> I also made the **reloadabale property as true** in tomcat server's
>   context.xml. Also i added entries for these files in
>   **WatchedResource** tag. But nothing works as this checks for the files only within the exploded war.

Please help me resolving this issue.

Comment: Do you think Hibernate supports reloading the config file?